# nuget restore fails in codebuild, but works locally and in docker

Tags: docker, aws-codebuild

I'm attempting to get aws code-pipeline and code-build working for a .Net framework web application.

My buildspec looks like this...

```
version: 0.2

env:
  variables:
    PROJECT: TestCodeBuild1
    DOTNET_FRAMEWORK: 4.7.2
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - dir
      - nuget restore $env:PROJECT.sln
      - msbuild $env:PROJECT.sln /p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v$env:DOTNET_FRAMEWORK /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site" /p:PackageAsSingleFile=false /p:OutDir=C:\codebuild\artifacts\ /t:Package
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: 'C:\codebuild\artifacts\_PublishedWebsites\${env:PROJECT}_Package\Archive\'
```

The "dir" line in the buildspec was put there just to confirm it's is in the correct directory, and the required folders are there, which they are.

It's using the following image for the build environment...

```
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.7.2
```

When it runs, I get the following warning, when it gets to the nuget restore...

```
WARNING: Error reading msbuild project information, ensure that your input solution or project file is valid. NETCore and UAP projects will be skipped, only packages.config files will be restored.
```

The msbuild then subsequently also fails, but I'm guessing that may be related to the fact that nuget restore hasn't worked correctly.

I've confirmed that the project and solution is correct. If I run "nuget restore" from my local environment it works fine, without any errors or warnings.

I thought perhaps it was something particular to the docker environment, so I tried creating a Dockerfile like so...

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.7.2

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN nuget restore
```

This also works fine. "docker build ." runs without any warnings.

So I'm not sure why this is failing in code-build. As far as I can see everything is correct, and I haven't found any way to reproduce the issue locally.

Other forum posts just suggest correcting package issues in the project files. However there are no issues as far as I can see with the project packages.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @joe No, unfortunately I never figured this out. I've decided to continue using Azure DevOps. Windows support in codebuild seems to be quite rudimentary and seems not to be ready to use for production applications.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did and it seems to have worked:

1.: *buildspec.yml*

```
version: 0.2
env:
  variables:
    SOLUTION: .\MyProject.sln
    PACKAGE_DIRECTORY: .\packages
    DOTNET_FRAMEWORK: 4.6.2
    PROJECT: MyProjectName
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - .\nuget restore
      - >-
        msbuild $env:PROJECT.csproj
        /p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v$env:DOTNET_FRAMEWORK
        /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployIisAppPath="MySite"
        /p:PackageAsSingleFile=false /p:OutDir=C:\codebuild\artifacts\
        /t:Package
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: 'C:\codebuild\artifacts\_PublishedWebsites\${env:PROJECT}_Package\Archive\'
```

2. I then downloaded nuget.exe (https://www.nuget.org/downloads) and put it into the root directory (the same directory as the .sln file)

When I pushed my commit to the branch on AWS, ".\nuget.exe" successfully restored all packages. I am using the Docker image "microsoft/aspnet:4.6.2".

Hope it helps someone.